# In which setting would you expect model found by LARS to differ most from the model found by exhaustive search?

Tags: regression, model-selection

A bit more info; suppose that

1. you know before hand how many variables to select and that you set the complexity penalty in the LARS procedure such as to have exactly that many variables with non 0 coefficients,
2. computation costs are not an issue (the total number of variable is small, say 50),
3. that all the variables (y,x) are continuous.

In what setting would the LARS model (i.e. the OLS fit of those variables having non zero coefficients in the LARS fit) be most different from a model with the same number of coefficients but found through exhaustive search (a la regsubsets())?

Edit: I'm using 50 variables and 250 observations with the real coefficients drawn from a standard gaussian except for 10 of the variables having 'real' coefficients of 0 (and all the features being strongly correlated with one another). These settings are obviously not good as the differences between the two set of selected variables are minute. This is really a question about what type of data configuration should one simulate to get the most differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the description of the LARS algorithm: http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/simple.html It kind of ignores the correlation between the regressors so I would venture to guess that it might miss out on the fit in case of multicollinearity.

Comment: that's what's motivating my question actually. I have simulated settings with 50 variables where the largest value of the vif is in excess of 30 and i still see very few differences (for example in terms of R^2 of the selected models) between the two approach.

Comment: I myself have found different answers with stepAIC and lars and would imagine that my issue is to be treated with group LASSO - it is not about the VIF of the whole matrix, but a number of clusters of correlated variables.

Comment: Interresting...how do you generate such data? (i.e. with clusters of correlated variables)

Comment: Stack together a number of independent groups with correlation inside of them. I myself have a bunch of same questions asked about a number of brands - people tend to like the brand of their choice and dislike others.

Answer (score 3):

The more features you have, in relation to the number of samples, the more over-fitting you are likely to get with the exaustive search method than with LARS.  The penalty term used in LARS imposes a nested structure of increasingly complex models, indexed by a single regularisation parameter, so the "degrees of freedom" of feature selection with LARS is fairly low.  For exaustive search, there is effectvely one (binary) degree of freedom per feature, which means that exaustive search is better able to exploit the random variability in the feature selection criterion due to the random sampling of the data.  As a result, the exaustive search model is likely to be severely ofer-fitted to the feature selection criterion, as the "hypothesis class" is larger.

Comment: Your answer seems unrelated to my question. To make it clear: I am really interested in generating situations where the subset of variables selected as active by LARS would be most different from those selected by exhaustive search, with this measured by, say, the difference in R^2 between the LARS model and the exhaustive search model _with same number of active variable_. Can you think of any adversary case where this difference would be large? Can you re-phrase your answer in these terms?

Comment: My answer is directly related to your question.  The degree of over-fitting is not controlled only by the number of features, but by the values of the weights.  Thus it is possible to over-fit without using more features.  LARS puts a penalty on the magnitude of the weights, so it doesn't choose features that only reduce the squared loss at the expense of large magnitude weights, which is why it is less prone to over-fitting.  Exaustive search methods are basically a recipe for over-fitting, so you will get very different solutions in situations where over-fitting is likely to occurr.

Comment: Ok, i get your point: it comes from something i glossed over in my original question (and hopefully made more clear now). I'm really comparing apple to apples here (i.e. the selected models), or in other words, the (R^2 of the) OLS fit using those variable selected by LARS and the (R^2 of the) OLS fit using those variables selected by exhaustive search. I'm not  directly using the LARS coefficients....

Comment: A badly over-fitted exhaustive search model will have a better OLS fit on the calibration data and worse OLS fit on test data than you are likely to get with a LARS model.  Again this will be most extreme in situations likely to encourage over-fitting (many features, few samples).  The main purpose of LARS is over-fitting avoidance, so that is where you are likely to see the greatest differences, regardless of the criterion (weight values, OLS, etc.)

Comment: "A badly over-fitted exhaustive...LARS model" i appreciate the effort, but i think you lost me again: i'm not trying to find which one is best, i'm looking for situations where they give most differing subsets. "(many features, few samples)." can you put numbers there? i have n(sample size)250 and p(#number of features)=50. Is this off? " so that is where you are likely to see the greatest differences" what do you mean 'where' can you explicit what data-generation model would get us 'there'?

Comment: It isn't orthogonal, one model is unlikely to be better than another without being different.  In situations where over-fitting is likely, an exaustive search based model is likely to be unstable, i.e. if you collect a different 500 samples, you are likely to get a different set of features.  LARS on the other hand is liklely to be more stable.  Whether 50 features and 500 samples is likley to result in overfitting depends on the nature of the dataset, but it is certainly possible.  Exhaustive search is liable to pick features that explain the variability peculiar to this sample; LARS less so.

Comment: Ok, i understand your point, and it is indeed a valid one. But given that i'm generating the data here, for the sole purpose of making this measure of difference i have described as large as possible (within the constraints of having no more than 50 features all in all) what type of situations can i generate on which a fixed size subset (say 10 of of 50 variable are allowed to be active) selected by the two approaches will reliably show as little overlap as possible?

Comment: It might help if you could explain *why* you would want to do that.  I suspect the thing you need to look at is the magnitudes of the weights of the true model as well as that of the distribution of the data.  Penalised regression models (LASSO, LARS, Elaris net, ridge regression) have a prior on the expected distribution of weights, so if you have a dataset where this is invalid, that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm looking for adversarial cases. That's a very good insight you gave there (and i think quiet close to that suggested by the first responder). Could you point to a concrete case where this causes LARS and SS to reliably pick widely non overlapping subsets of variables?